# Ramp-up test report in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Could you tell me, please, when you perform the ramp-up test in JMeter, which results/metrics do you include in the report?
Could you show me, please, what it looks like?
What structure of report should I use?
Does any free pattern(s) of this report exist?
Where can I see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what type of testing are you performing with your `rump-up tests`?
Defining load increase using Ramp-Up Period value or in any other way is only instrument to implement concrete test with concrete goal, that will determine params to monitor and metrics to collect.

Suppose you are working on load-testing scenarios, so you can possibly look at least onto following links below:

- [Load, Stress, Performance Test Terms, Deliverables, Profiles and Reports](http://www.wilsonmar.com/perfrpt.htm)
- [Load Test Configuration – using a stepped ramp](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/2008/07/load-test-configuration-using-a-stepped-ramp/)
- [Design a Load Test that Measures What You Really Want to Know](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/2012/01/design-a-load-test-that-measures-what-you-really-want-to-know/)
- [Estimating Load test ramp-up times](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/blog/2009/05/estimating-load-test-ramp-up-times/)
- example reports on the [loadosophia](http://loadosophia.org/)
- [JMeterreport plugin: Nice html reports of functional testresults](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-969)

Comment: I need to perform capasity assessment.
I'm thankful you for your links collection. ))